# How to install GTK widget factory via Apt?

Tags: apt, gnome, themes, gtk3

The GTK widget factory is useful for visualizing and creating GTK themes.
Search engine has led me to some websites<sup>[1](https://www.jasong-designs.com/2015/05/28/how-to-install-a-widget-factory-in-linux/),[2](https://github.com/valr/awf)</sup> which suggest building it from sources or
adding a PPA. Isn't there a package in the main repository that installs it?

I have also tried

```
apt-cache search widget factory
apt-cache search gtk factory
```

but nothing appropriate was found.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It took some digging but I finally found it [in Linux Mint's forum](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1480325&sid=b49ab4422ad0871c7721d788b6450620#p1480325).

```
sudo apt install gtk-3-examples
```

Issue `gtk3-widget-factory` to start it.

Comment: Using forums for searching is not so good as using official [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&section=all&arch=any&keywords=gtk3-widget-factory&searchon=contents).

Comment: @N0rbert Nice, I didn't know about that! I'm afraid there is no way to make such a search with `apt-cache`? If not, what a pity.

Comment: For local search you can use `apt-file`. See its [man-page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/apt-file.1.html) for details.